# Cannot import tensorflow pretrained model multiple times

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to use a pre-trained MobileNet for transfer learning however i am running into a problem when i am trying to run the same command the second time

```
import tensorflow as tf
try:
    del g1
except:
    pass
g1 = tf.Graph()
with g1.as_default():
    base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=(160,160,3),
                                                       include_top=False,
                                                       weights='imagenet')
```

I can run this cell in jupyter alright the first time but the second time i try to run this i get 
`TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder_207:0", shape=(160,), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.`
However, I can run this cell multiple times perfectly fine

```
base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=(160,160,3),
                                                       include_top=False,
                                                       weights='imagenet')
```